# Mobile push contact registration via marketing cloud standard api

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, marketingcloudapi

Is it recommended and viable that the mobile app uses the standard marketing cloud [Create Contact API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/createContacts.htm) instead of using the contact registration of mobile push sdk for [Android](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/) and [IOS](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/)?

Answer (score 2):

For push, it is not recommended that you register devices/contacts outside of the provided SDKs.

Comment: @[Bill Mote] would you mind to expand a little bit your feedback and explain the reason why is not recommended? Additionally now the question is become for the entire mobile push sdk: if it's viable and recommended to replace it entirely (not only for contact registration) with [Marketing Cloud APIs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/index-api.htm) .

Comment: As of 20200123 the Contact/Device registration routes, analytics routes as well as the device and message routes are not publicly documented routes and can change without notice.  What is the reason for avoiding the SDKs?  We have a BILLION registered devices across a lot of customers.

Comment: As per my understanding it's seems that the company in charge of the mobile app development saves effort using the API instead of the SDK and do not fully support the integration of that kind of SDK. What do you mean by "routes are not publicly documented routes and can change without notice"? Do you mean that is a different set of API, not the ones documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/index-api.htm)?

Comment: That is correct.